# Spring boot oath2 Invalid access token

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am trying a very simple example:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServer extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
       clients.inMemory()
                    .withClient("my-api").secret("{noop}secret")
                    .authorizedGrantTypes("client_credentials")
                    .scopes("resource-server-read", "resource-server-write");

    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) throws Exception {
        security.allowFormAuthenticationForClients().checkTokenAccess("permitAll()");
    }
}
```

and the SimpleAuthorizationServerApplication:

```
@RestController
@EnableResourceServer
@SpringBootApplication
public class SimpleAuthorizationServerApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SimpleAuthorizationServerApplication.class, args);
    }

    @RequestMapping("/validateUser")
    public Principal user(Principal user) {
        return user;
    }

}
```

...and then the resource (in another module of the same app):

```
@RestController
public class MyController {

    @GetMapping("hello/world")
    public String helloWorld() {
        return "helloWorld";
    }

}
```

...and

```
@EnableResourceServer
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

Although I do get the token nicely from http://localhost:7070/oauth/token :

```
{
    "access_token": "05a0adeb-751d-4b4b-a9f5-177e82ac9826",
    "token_type": "bearer",
    "expires_in": 42167,
    "scope": "resource-server-read resource-server-write"
}
```

when calling the resource http://localhost:8080/hello/world with the authorisation bearer token, I get

```
{
    "error": "invalid_token",
    "error_description": "Invalid access token: 05a0adeb-751d-4b4b-a9f5-177e82ac9826"
}
```

My pom dependencies:

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

application.yml on resource end :

```
security:
  oauth2:
    resource:
      userInfoUri: http://localhost:7070/oauth/validateUser
```

It seems that something is wrongly configured, but I cannot figure it out what, therefore I need help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set this:

```
security.oauth2.resource.userInfoUri=http://localhost:7070/oauth/...
```

Comment: yes , on the resource side in application.yml I have :
  security oauth2:
    resource:
      userInfoUri: http://localhost:7070/oauth/validateUser (properly indented)

Comment: Tried, same result :(      curl -i http://localhost:8080/optimization/hello/world -H "Authorization: Bearer f782e198-fedb-49de-9131-d7c6f74c4ea8"
HTTP/1.1 401 
WWW-Authenticate: Bearer realm="oauth2-resource", error="invalid_token", error_description="Invalid access token: f782e198-fedb-49de-9131-d7c6f74c4ea8"
Cache-Control: no-store
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
{"error":"invalid_token","error_description":"Invalid access token: f782e198-fedb-49de-9131-d7c6f74c4ea8"}%

Comment: could you try /validateUser endpoint on the authorization server?
AuthorizationServer has to be ResourceServer of that endpoint...

And all other apps, just Resources Servers

Comment: http://localhost:7070/oauth/validateUser works fine

Comment: works with token? can you paste the response?

Comment: curl  http://localhost:7070/oauth/validateUser -H "Authorization: Bearer ea457082-11c0-486d-89f6-ced51861d0f5"

Comment: {"authorities":[],"details":{"remoteAddress":"0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1","sessionId":null,"tokenValue":"ea457082-11c0-486d-89f6-ced51861d0f5","tokenType":"Bearer","decodedDetails":null},"authenticated":true,"userAuthentication":null,"credentials":"","clientOnly":true,

Comment: "oauth2Request":{"clientId":"my-api","scope":["resource-server-read","resource-server-write"],"requestParameters":{"grant_type":"client_credentials"},"resourceIds":[],"authorities":[],"approved":true,"refresh":false,"redirectUri":null,"responseTypes":[],"extensions":{},"refreshTokenRequest":null,"grantType":"client_credentials"},"principal":"my-api","name":"my-api"}%

Comment: would it be this : "resourceIds":[] the problem ?

Comment: take a look at https://gitlab.com/carlosmiranda-java/oauth-server
please, check properties, and postman collections, I tried to clean most of it...
security is "user == password"

Comment: I will have a look , thanks a lot !!! .Meanwhile I have debug it as well.the problem is that two token store instances are used.One in which the authorization server saves the token, and another one in which it looks for existing token.This 2nd one is of course empty hence the 'invalid token' error